# How to make VSTS email me if somebody @mention me on discussion

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to email if somebody @mention me on discussion.
I know that it is possible :)
I have tried to set on setting --> notification, but without result.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using VSTS or TFS?

Comment: VSTS. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

It’s already the default manners.

When someone is mentioned in work item discussion, he/she will receive the email notification by default.

[image]
[image]

You can also find achieved request [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/5886821-alerts-based-on-discussion-additions).

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why it is doesn't work on my account.

Comment: First, please make sure the user you mentioned in work item discussion corresponding to the email address correctly. If the corresponding email address still can not receive the email notification, you can report the issue in developer community (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Comment: Since you actually recieve the email as you said in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159786/how-to-make-vsts-email-me-if-somebody.html, you can mark the answer (√ symbol on the left of answer). And it will benefit other who have similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the person that was not getting the notifications had a different email setup in their profile. If you hover over the @person you will see the email that is setup, if that is the issue, then update the Person profile with the proper email

Comment: Good catch. I had this same problem with a colleague that was using an old email. We did not know that the contact email could be different from the account email!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you and the people you want to notify are setup with notifications

[image]

[image]